# Simple VBA Coding

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to writing VBA code so hopefully this isn't too easy for you all, but hopefully you can help me get over this learning hump I've yet to surmount. I'm writing a code to add amounts to current prices and I want to combine the following subroutines so I don't have to run each code seperately. Here they are:

```
Sub addingincurrentdate()

    Workbooks("fuel prices w. macro program 2015").Activate
    Worksheets("sheet1").Activate

    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Date
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"

End Sub

Sub hoprice()



    Workbooks("fuel prices w. macro program 2015").Activate
    Worksheets("sheet1").Activate

    Dim myvalue As Variant

    myvalue = InputBox("How much do you want to add to the #2 Heating Oil Price?")


    Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value + myvalue

End Sub

Sub addingDieselprice()

    Workbooks("fuel prices w. macro program 2015").Activate
    Worksheets("sheet1").Activate

    Dim myvalue As Variant

    myvalue = InputBox("How much do you want to add to the Off Rd Delivered Price?")

    Range("D2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value + myvalue


End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to make your title more descriptive of the problem you're having or question you're asking. *Simple VBA coding* provides zero information that isn't already available in the tags (that you're using VBA). Your title should indicate the topic of your question in a way that is useful to future readers of this site in a search result. You've also not asked a question of any sort, or made any effort to *combine* anything yourself first.

Comment: Did you find any of the answers below useful?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you could just put a `main` sub below the other three:

```
Sub main()
    addingincurrentdate
    hoprice
    addingDieselprice
End Sub
```

Then -- just invoke `main` once and it will call your three subs in turn. It would also be possible to combine them into a single sub, but if they are already working it is simple enough to call them from a single sub.

Answer (score 0):

Just put all of the code in each macro into one and remove the duplicate lines (I've also removed and combined the select statements as these aren't needed)

```
Sub Combined()

    Workbooks("fuel prices w. macro program 2015").Activate
    Worksheets("sheet1").Activate

    with Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
        .Value = Date
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
    end with

    Dim myvalue As Variant

    myvalue = InputBox("How much do you want to add to the #2 Heating Oil Price?")

    Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value + myvalue

    myvalue = InputBox("How much do you want to add to the Off Rd Delivered Price?")

    Range("D2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value + myvalue

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Both answers so far are pretty good. You also have the option of doing something like this:

```
Sub CombinedMethods(WhatWork As String)

    Dim myvalue As Variant

    Workbooks("fuel prices w. macro program 2015").Activate
    Worksheets("sheet1").Activate

    If LCase(WhatWork) = "formatdate" Then
        Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Date
        ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If LCase(WhatWork) = "hoprice" Then
        myvalue = InputBox("How much do you want to add to the #2 Heating Oil Price?")
        Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value + myvalue
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If LCase(WhatWork) = "dieselprice" Then
        myvalue = InputBox("How much do you want to add to the Off Rd Delivered Price?")
        Range("D2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value + myvalue
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MsgBox "Expected to receive either formatdate, hoprice or dieselprice as argument. Received " & WhatWork & ". Exiting", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Unexpected argument"

End Sub

Sub Main()
    CombineMethods ("formatdate")
    CombineMethods ("hoprice")
    CombineMethods ("dieselprice")
End Sub
```

That way you call a single procedure with different arguments and the procedure does appropriate work based on the supplied argument.

Answer (score 0):

Just simplify it all into one sub:

```
Sub AllSubsInOne()

With Workbooks("fuel prices w. macro program 2015")
    With .Sheets("sheet1")
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
        With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            .Value = .Offset(-1, 0).Value + InputBox("How much do you want to add to the #2 Heating Oil Price?")
        End With
        With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            .Value = .Offset(-1, 0).Value + InputBox("How much do you want to add to the Off Rd Delivered Price?")
        End With
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is call each sub with something like this

```
sub call_other_subs()

call addingincurrentdate()
call hoprice()
call addingDieselprice()

end sub
```

Try that with and without the word "call" to see how it works for you.  Also try it with and without parentheses "()". Try those get a better idea of how these things work.

Also I suggest you do some internet searching on how to call a VBA subroutine from another subroutine and that will get you any number of examples with variations on these ideas.